# Please help me with this smooth floating scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, scroll

Well, I have this navigation menu which is static but I want to make it flow smoothly whenever user scrolls his page down or up... Please help with the code because I already have tried to do something but everything went bad.

Code:

```
<div id="menu">

        <ul>

            <li class="page_item">

                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="Go home">Home</a>

            </li>

            <?php wp_list_pages('&title_li=&exclude=6386'); ?>

            <?php

            if(is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('subscriber')) :

            ?>

            <li class="page_item">

                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/tasks/" title="Your task list">Tasks</a>

            </li>

            <?php

            endif;

            ?>

            <?php

            if(!is_user_logged_in()) :

            ?>

            <li class="page_item">

                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/">Log in</a>

            </li>

            <?php

            endif;

            ?>

        </ul>

    </div>
```

I want this whole thing to float, how am I supposed to do this?

I tried to add this script and give menu class="scroller":

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>60){
        $('.scroller').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('.scroller').css('top', 0);
    } else {
        $('.scroller').css('position', 'relative');
        $('.scroller').css('top', 60);
    }
});
```

});

But no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, because you're using jQuery, you don't have to bind the `onLoad` event to do it. Just bind the `onDomReady` pseudo-event, without to create any other class (you already have the ID). That said, you need to listen for the `onScroll` event of the document. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('scroll',function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $menu = $('#menu'),
            scrl = $this.scrollTop(),
            menuHeight = $menu.height();

        if( scrl > menuHeight ) {
            $('#menu').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': 0
            });
        } else {
            $('#menu').css({
                'position': 'relative',
                'top': menuHeight
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This should works fine for your needs.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/39qrU/) to test the code.

**EDIT**: code updated to dynamically handle every menu height.

Comment: Thank you both. Solved my problem with the help.

Comment: By the way, when I use your script, the menu quickly bumps up to top and then starts floating downwards from initial place when scrolling.. Why? How to fix that? I don't want the menu to bump up :/

Comment: my bad, sorry. I've updated the code. Change `absolute` to `relative` in `else` statement and it should works.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property 'top' doesn't work with relative positioning. Try absolute instead.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>60){
        $('.scroller').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('.scroller').css('top', 0);
    } else {
        $('.scroller').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('.scroller').css('top', 60);
    }
});
```

EDIT : You'll need to add a margin to the element above or below where you want the scrollbar to appear to create a gap for it.